Combine Two Instances on one Geometry Node
I'm trying to achieve the effect I've "faked" using two node trees in the example below. Two different instances (colors, facing opposite directions) starting from opposite ends of a plane, and mixing in the centre. Done properly in one node tree, there shouldn't be much in the way of intersection, unlike my terrible example. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for looking!
LM

Copy the nodes that make the red instances into the nodetree of the blue instances and combine them with a Join Geometry node?

A useful pointer, thank you.

You can use a single Poisson distribution to avoid overlap:


That's a successful outcome... my own version doesn't work so well. Looking at the numbers, the scale may be very different on yours, which could be a useful insight.

Way better than mine

@GreenBeetle, you can use the "attribute statictics" to get min and max position to feed to the map range

@Daniel Möller. Good tip, thank you.

You could use the gradient as a factor for the distribution.
Here we have two distributions, each using one gradient (which is the inverse of the other).
One distributions pulls red Suzzanes and another pulls blue Suzzanes


Excellent! thank you, Daniel. Simpler in one way (and far more complicated in another) than I expected. I couldn't have come up with that by myself.

@GreenBeetle Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind. I was on my phone when I wrote the comment above and could not give it a proper answer myself.

Every little helps, I say.
